# Adding a printf line in C program causes compilation errors from different part of the program

Tags: c, gcc

[Compiler Explorer Link](https://cpg.godbolt.org/z/xeeK8xGMb)

I have a small program, playing out with stretchy buffers idea in C. I test it in Compiler Explorer. I enable flags `-Wall -Werror -Wpedantic`. I have no problem running it with Clang, it shows ne errors. But here is the sample, and I want to talk about a weird behaviour of GCC that I observe in Compiler Explorer.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef unsigned char uc;
typedef unsigned long ul;

typedef struct {
    ul len;
    ul capacity;
    uc* data;
} dyn_arr_hdr;

#define _dyn_arr_get_hdr_(buf) (dyn_arr_hdr*)((uc*)(buf) - 2 * sizeof(ul))

void* _dyn_array_expand_if_needed_(void* buf, ul elem_size) {
    dyn_arr_hdr* head = _dyn_arr_get_hdr_(buf);
    if(head->len * 2 <= head->capacity)
        return buf;
    // weird thing, comment-in this printf and get compile time error in gcc
    // printf("expanding...\n");
    ul new_cap = head->capacity * 2;
    ul new_size = elem_size * new_cap;
    head->data = realloc(head->data, new_size);
    head->capacity = new_cap;
    return head->data;
}

void* dyn_arr_init(void*buf, ul elem_size) {
    dyn_arr_hdr* head = malloc(sizeof(dyn_arr_hdr));
    head->len = 0;
    head->capacity = 4;
    head->data = malloc(head->capacity * elem_size);
    return head->data;
}

#define dyn_arr_size(buf) ((_dyn_arr_get_hdr_(buf))->len)

#define dyn_arr_push_back(buf, n) buf = _dyn_array_expand_if_needed_(buf, sizeof(*buf)); \
                                  buf[dyn_arr_size(buf)++] = (n)
int main(void) {
    int* v = NULL;
    printf("ptr=%p\n", (void*)v);
    v = dyn_arr_init(v, sizeof(int));
    printf("ptr=%p\n", (void*)v);
    
    dyn_arr_push_back(v, 42);
    dyn_arr_push_back(v, 43);
    dyn_arr_push_back(v, 44);
    dyn_arr_push_back(v, 45);
    dyn_arr_push_back(v, 46);
    dyn_arr_push_back(v, 47);
    dyn_arr_push_back(v, 48);
    dyn_arr_push_back(v, 49);

    for(ul i = 0; i < dyn_arr_size(v); ++i)
        printf("val=%d\n", v[i]);
    return dyn_arr_size(v);
}
```

This program also compiles and works fine in GCC. Weird thing is, in the `_dyn_arr_expand_if_needed_` function, there is a commented-out line `printf("expanding...")`. As soon as I comment-in that line, GCC tries giving me some array access out of bounds errors in the if-statement above the printf. I can't really figure out how GCC is behaving in this case. I am sure there is some mistake in some place of my code but just can't figure out. Especially when things seem to be mostly working without that printf.

Sorry for weird title, since I can't figure out what is wrong or what is the problem; it is also hard to describe the problem in the title. I am open for edits and suggestions on the title.

NOTE: This error I get using GCC 13.2 and GCC trunk in Compiler Explorer. Also, this question in fact has two minimal reproducible examples. To get the one that is failing, just comment-in the printf line I mentioned in the question. Just kept the examples differing with comments instead of seperate MREs, in order to don't get the question too long to read.

The error I get from GCC:

> In function 'dyn_array_expand_if_needed',inlined from 'main' at > :47:5:
>
> :18:12: error: array subscript 0 is outside array bounds > of 'void[16]' [-Werror=array-bounds=]
>
> 18 |     if(head->len * 2 <= head->capacity)
> |        ~~~~^~~~~
> In function 'dyn_arr_init',
> inlined from 'main' at :44:9:
>
> :33:18: note: at offset -16 into object of size 16 > allocated by 'malloc'
>   33 |     head->data = malloc(head->capacity * elem_size);
>      |                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: Identifiers that start with `_` [are reserved at file scope](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.3): "All identifiers that begin with an underscore are always reserved for use as identifiers with file scope in both the ordinary and tag name spaces."  I have no idea why that naming pattern is taught so much.

Comment: Please provide two instead of only one [mre], one for "works" one for "gives the following compiler error" - and a full verbatim, textual quote of the error directly here. I pretty much understand what you mean with the `//...` but at this point lets avoid any chance for misunderstanding.

Comment: AddressSanitizer says there's a buffer overflow without the `printf`.  https://godbolt.org/z/zqdh6EYhf

Comment: @Andrew Henle OK, that is something I did not know and I will definitely research it further. But removing initial `_`s from my identifiers still does not solve the issue I am seeing, just updating on your comment.

Comment: Which version of gcc is giving you compilation errors?

Comment: Could you make your MREs without the macros?

Comment: To help people answer your question, you'll need to be more specific about the error.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the exact errors you get from your [mcve] (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Comment: Can't reproduce:  https://godbolt.org/z/Tsh3jz31Y

Comment: I added the compile errors from GCC.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Thanks for pointing into correct direction. I just want to understand how that printf makes GCC see this issue at compile time. On sanitizer as you suggest, both versions seem to be causing sanitizer errors.

Comment: If you have a copy of the code in Compiler Explorer that exhibits the error, you should link to it.  The code you've posted (with the `printf` uncommented) with the given compiler options in CE does not.

Comment: I added the link to CE.

Comment: The error messages seem clear. Do you have a problem interpreting them?

Comment: Yes, I can't udnerstand why this causes array access out of bounds. To my eyes, it seems like everything is within reason. In fact, as I said, it just works if I comment-in that totally unrelated printf line and works just fine without that line. That makes it even weirder for me to understand and analyze.

Comment: The implementation seems broken. You have your array separated into the header and the data. The header has a pointer to the data, which is OK. The data has no pointer back to the header. It looks like you have an illusion of being able to go from the data back to the header by doing some hocus pocus magic in _dyn_arr_get_hdr_. No, you cannot do that, forget about this idea. Any success you have so far in doing that is due to pure luck, and you are running out of it.

Comment: @meguli, Why does `_dyn_array_expand_if_needed_()` return `head->data;` and not `buf`?

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI But why? I have a pointer to data, and I know this pointer is the third element in the struct. Shouldn't it be possible to subtract the offset of that field from this uint8_t pointer and get to the beginning address of the header object?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica In usage, it is then assigned back to buf as in `buf = _dyn_array_expand_if_needed_(buf, sizeof(*buf))`.

Comment: @meguli The addition/subtraction is prone to failure as 1) it does not count for alignment 2) code has much casting that defeats type checking.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I tried using the `offsetof` macro as well, to address the issue of alignment and padding etc. but that did not work eaither. `#define dyn_arr_get_hdr(buf) (dyn_arr_hdr*)((uint8_t*)(buf) - offsetof(dyn_arr_hdr, data))`

Comment: @meguli Notice `dyn_arr_init()` assigns `head`, yet `head` is lost on function return.  It appears you want only 1 allocation (prefix data and array data) in that function and then to copy the prefix data in later re-allocations.

Comment: Tip: there is no need for any casting to accomplish this task.

Comment: No, it doesn't work like you describe, not even close. You could in principle go from the *address* of `data` to the address of the header. But you don't have the address of `data`. You only have its value. Use a debugger, stop in  `_dyn_array_expand_if_needed_`, examine the `*head`, Do you see what you expect to see?

Comment: Thanks, now it makes sense to me as well. I guess the case that it was working as expected with printf added was just luck as you said, compiler being randomly favorable for me in terms of adressing/allocating etc.

Comment: You may want to read up on *flexible array members*. What you want to do is doable with this language feature.

Comment: @meguli  n. m. could be an AI is right.  Consider using `typedef struct {
size_t len; size_t capacity; max_align_t data[]; } dyn_arr_hdr;` as the first step.

Answer (score 3):

> GCC tries giving me some array access out of bounds errors

I can't explain why these only occur with the `printf` uncommented, but I understand why you are getting the error. I have to say I'm impressed that gcc detects it. Or maybe it's a coincidence and I'm about to describe an unrelated problem.

Your macro `_dyn_arr_get_hdr_(buf)` accesses pointer offsets `2 * sizeof(unsigned long)` before `buf`. This is a nonsense because `buf` is the address of a malloc'd block of RAM that could be anywhere and is almost certainly not contiguous with the header (many malloc implementations use the same trick you are trying to use to store the metas data).

If you want this trick to work, you need to use a [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member) at the end of your `struct` and malloc it all in one block. The `struct` would look like this

```
typedef struct {
    ul len;
    ul capacity;
    uc data[];  // Flexible array member
} dyn_arr_hdr;
```

`data` is now an array of indeterminate length and not a pointer. This is an important distinction because treating it as a pointer will give you an address with a known fixed offset from the start of the `struct`.

`sizeof` will give the length of the struct as if the last member was empty so to malloc a block for it including space for `data` you do this

```
dyn_arr_hdr* head = malloc(sizeof(dyn_arr_hdr) + initial_capacity * elem_size);
```

Now `head->data` will decay to a pointer within the `struct` and you may be able to do your arithmetic to get the beginning of the `struct`, although, you need to be careful because there is no guarantee that there is no padding between all the elements.

That said, I would urge you to turn this around and give people an opaque pointer to the `struct` instead and provide functions / macros to get all of the internal elements including the data.

Answer (score 2):

The error messages you're seeing appear when optimization is turned up to `-O3` and do not appear at `-O2`.  These are not language errors but the result of source code analysis that gcc is performing at that optimization level, and apparently the presence of the `printf` call is affecting how that analysis is functioning.

What the gcc analysis is telling you (as does valgrind if you compile at a lower optimization level and run) is that your code is accessing memory outside the bounds of an allocated memory block.  This is because you're returning the *content* of `head->data` which is a separate block of memory from which `head` was allocated, so counting backward in memory from the *value* of `head->data` reaching into addresses you shouldn't be touching.

Using a flexible array member as mentioned in the other answer would be one way of solving the issue, however this restricts you to a specific data type, not a generalized type as you currently have.

So the way to handle this is to remove the `data` member from the header and to allocate space for the header and the data in a single allocation.

So your header structure should be modified to look like this:

```
typedef struct {
    struct {
      ul len;
      ul capacity;
    } _Alignas(max_align_t);
} dyn_arr_hdr;
```

We're using an anonymous nested `struct` here to force the parent `struct` to be aligned to the maximum alignment.  This will allow you to place any type of data immediately after the header without having to worry about the alignment of the data.

Your init routine will now look like this:

```
void* dyn_arr_init(void*buf, ul elem_size) {
    dyn_arr_hdr* head = malloc(sizeof(dyn_arr_hdr) + (4 * elem_size));
    head->len = 0;
    head->capacity = 4;
    return head + 1;
}
```

Here we can see that we're allocating space for the header plus the initial capacity at once, and we return a pointer to right after the header, specifically `head + 1`.  The memory at this address is still untyped so you can put anything there.

Then the macro to recover the header will look like this:

```
#define _dyn_arr_get_hdr_(buf) ((dyn_arr_hdr*)buf - 1)
```

This is valid because the base buffer is a valid pointer to one-past a single element array of `dyn_arr_hdr`, so casting to that pointer type and subtracting one gives you back the address of the header.

Then the expand function will reallocate space for the combined header plus data and return a pointer to just past the reallocated header:

```
head = realloc(head, new_size + sizeof(dyn_arr_hdr));
head->capacity = new_cap;
return head + 1;
```